# Nothing has changed after adding a table to SQL Server Management Studio in Azure project in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I created the DB in Azure, then connected SQL Server Management Studio, added the table. But in my project in Visual Studio there is no that table after I refreshed.

Comment: Can you please post the command you executed on the database and any response/output that it gives you in SSMS?

Comment: I solved this trouble today with the help of Deploy DB To MS Azure DB in context menu of SSMS and it works.